# Is it possible to override the SharePoint 2010 OOB search result security trimming?

Tags: search, security-trimming

I've built and deployed a custom security trimmer based on the ISecurityTrimmer2 interface. I have verified that it is running for the content source + crawl rule that I intended. However, it only gets called *after* the default out-of-the-box security trimmer runs. I would like it to run *instead of* the default trimmer. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom security trimmers can be used for additional trimming, it doesn't replace the OOTB security trimmer. 
As far as I know you can't replace the OOTB security trimmer.